# How can include css for only nested view in AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, view, nested

I have create a nested view like

```
 <div ng-show="nestedView" style="height:inherit" ui-view="nestedView@"></div>

.state('state', {
url: '/url', 
data: {
    css: [
        '/style.css',
    ]
},
views: {
    "": {
        templateUrl: '/html.html',
        controller: 'Controller',

    },
    "nestedView@": {
        templateUrl: '/template1.html',    
    },
    "otherView@":{
        templateUrl: '/template2.html',

    }
}})
```

This way I have 'style.css' only for this state, but I want to have style ONLY for 'nestedView' , ui-view="nestedView@

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you add a class property to the HTML elements (in nestedView), and use CSS selectors in your CSS files targeting these elements of specific classes.

HTML:

```
... class="nested-view title" ..
```

CSS:

```
.title.nested-view: {

}
```

You can also namespace your CSS classes..

```
.nested-view___title { }
.nested-view___table { }
```

etc..